# Can I load libraries compiled with aarch64 in x86_64 Android emulator?

Tags: android, x86-64, 64-bit, android-virtual-device, arm64

I'm trying to load a library compiled with aarch64 into the Android emulator.
I have to run it as x86_64 image because my environment cannot be run with arm. Is this possible?
If possible, I'd like to know how to package and load libraries.

copy aarch64 libraries in src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a and app package/install then, System.loadLibrary("library_name") cannot find the library.
When analyzing the apk, the library exists in lib/arm64-v8a.

If I put libraries compiled with aarch64 in the src/main/jniLibs/x86_64 directory, an error is displayed like

"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~iw2ueXOSINNyzySwRZuYHQ==/com.kt.tvcore.core-INqtBX86pYtwVH_sPxBKWw==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/libtest.so" is for EM_AARCH64 (183) instead of EM_X86_64 (62)"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible. A recent Mac can run arm64 with ease on an emulator

Comment: Thanks @hannes ach.. 
I have one more question. Is this link ([link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#30-0-0)) not related with this issue?

Comment: Same issue, read the same link.  Android is telling us this should work, but I'm having same issues as @oakyang